No puedo mostrar mis datos de mi bbdd en mayúsculas aunque las guarde en minúsculas?
mi problema es este, quiero saber si puedo mostrar mis datos en mayúsculas de mi bbdd, sin importar si esos datos los ingrese en minúsculas. Qué comando debo usar?

Para ello existe UPPER(). Por ejemplo: SELECT UPPER(laColumna) AS elAlias WHERE laColumnaDelCriterio=elCriterio;.

Gracias, me funcionó

Utiliza la función upper()

Returns the string str with all characters changed to uppercase according to the current character set mapping, or NULL if str is NULL.


Retorna la cadena str con todos los caracteres cambiados a mayúscula de acuerdo al mapa del juego de caracteres correspondiente, o NULL si str es NULL.

Así:
select miCampo, upper(miCampo) as miCampoMayusculas
  from miTabla;

